# How to avoid System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException in using Substring and length method

Tags: c#, substring

I'm creating a guessing game but it throws exception every time i put the correct char letter for the second time, but at first it seems fine but when i guess the correct letter again i get exception the exception was System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'startIndex cannot be larger than length of string. (Parameter 'startIndex') i tried all the posible way to fix this but i still can't find the correct solution hope you can help me.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String secret = " ", temp = " ", lalagyan = " ", answer="";
            int count = 0, num = 5;
            bool bol = false;
            var random = new Random();
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList { "one", "two", "three", "four" };
            int index = random.Next(list.Count);
            String word = list[index].ToString();

            for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
            {
                secret = word.Replace(word, "-");
                Console.Write(secret);
            }
            do
            {
                count++;
                Console.WriteLine("\nEnter a letter ");
                Console.WriteLine("Remaining Chances: " + num);
                Console.WriteLine("Clue: the word is " + word.Length + " letters");
                Console.Write("Answer: ");
                answer = Console.ReadLine();
                num--;
                Console.WriteLine("");
                for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
                {
                    //dito
                    if (answer.Equals(Convert.ToString(word[i])))
                    {
                        if (!bol)
                        {
                            temp += Convert.ToString(word[i]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //error around here
                            Console.Write("Correct Letter\n");
                            lalagyan = Convert.ToString(word[i]).Replace("-", answer);
                            temp = temp.Substring(0, i) + lalagyan + temp.Substring(i + 1, temp.Length - i + 1);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (!bol)
                        {
                            temp += "-";
                        }
                    }
                }
                bol = true;
                Console.Write(temp);
            }
            while (count < 5);
            Console.Write("\nEnter Your Final Guess: ");
            answer = Console.ReadLine();
            answer = answer.ToUpper();
            if (answer.Equals(index))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nYour Guess Is Correct!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nYour Guess Is Wrong!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
---
Enter a letter
Remaining Chances: 5
Clue: the word is 3 letters
Answer: o

 --o
Enter a letter
Remaining Chances: 4
Clue: the word is 3 letters
Answer: t

Correct Letter
t --o
Enter a letter
Remaining Chances: 3
Clue: the word is 3 letters
Answer: w

Correct Letter
tw--o
Enter a letter
Remaining Chances: 2
Clue: the word is 3 letters
Answer: o

Correct Letter
two-o
Enter a letter
Remaining Chances: 1
Clue: the word is 3 letters
Answer: o

Correct Letter
two-o
Enter Your Final Guess: two

Your Guess Is Wrong!
```

Comment: You're calling `temp.Substring()` twice.  Which one is throwing the exception?  Break them up into separate operations and debug to find out.  When the exception is thrown, what is the exact value of `temp`?  What is the exact value of `i`?

Comment: `temp.Substring(i + 1, temp.Length)` is almost certainly wrong. Note that the second parameter is the number of characters you want to extract, so maybe you mean `temp.Substring(i + 1, temp.Length - i - ))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArgumentOutOfRange` exception usually means that you are attempting to get a value that is outside the bounds of an array/collection.

In your case, if the users guess the last letter, the `i` value in this:

```
temp = temp.Substring(0, i) + lalagyan + temp.Substring(i + 1, temp.Length);
```

the first `temp.Substring(0,i)` will return the entire temp string, and the second `temp.Substring(i+1, temp.Length)` will try to return a string of length `temp.Length` starting at the last index - as this is not possible, it's likely causing the exception.

Review what this line of code should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument in `Substring` is the *length* of the substring, that's why

```
  temp.Substring(i + 1, temp.Length)
```

is erroneous: `temp.Length` is the length of the *entire* string and that's why it is *too large* for the substring. You can put it as

```
  temp = temp.Substring(0, i) + lalagyan + temp.Substring(i + 1);
```

Here `temp.Substring(i + 1)` means "start form `i + 1` and *up to the end*".

**Edit:** In case of *arbitrary* `i` you should check `i` as well:

```
  temp = 
      i <= 0 ? lalagyan + temp 
    : i >= temp.Length ? temp + lalagyan
    : temp.Substring(0, i) + lalagyan + temp.Substring(i + 1);
```

Comment: Note that if `i + 1` is already `>= temp.Length` you will get the exception too